# Probability of finding a 3 digit number six times within the first 1000 digits of pi

Tags: probability, pi

What is the probability of six (or more) appearances of a $3$ digit string within the first $1,000$ digits of $\pi$ (assuming $\pi$ was random). Not including rep digits, which may complicate the answer because of their increased likelihood (eg $1111$ could count as $2$ incidences of $111$).

I have calculated that the probability of finding at least one occurrence of a $3$ digit number within a random $1000$ digit string is $0.6323$ based on the formula

$$1-{(1-{0.1}^{3})}^{1000}$$

But the probability of six or more occurrence? Must be a longshot. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your 1000 digits you have 998 sequences of 3 digits. The probability to find there exactly $k$ times a given 3-digit number is:
$$
p(k)=\binom{998}{k}q^k(1-q)^{998-k},
$$
where $q=1/1000$. The probability of six or more occurrences can be then computed as:
$$
1-p(0)-p(1)-p(2)-p(3)-p(4)-p(5)\approx 0.000582.
$$

Comment: This method can't be right, because the answer must depend on which three-digit number you're looking for.   Suppose we had 3 digits instead of 1000, and suppose we were looking to find exactly 2 occurrences of a given two-digit number.  If the number is 12, there are exactly zero ways this can happen.  If the number is 11, there is exactly one way this can happen.

Comment: @WillO You are right that the above formula is not _exact_, due to those border effect you mention. But I don't expect them to be really relevant for 6 occurrences. Of course they would if we were to compute the probability of finding 300 occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

It is *relatively* safe to assume the digit triples are independent uniformly random numbers. Also, $1000$ is large enough to assume (esp. given the other approximation assumptions) a Poisson distribution for the the number of occurances of any given triple.
Thus out of $1000$ possible triples, we expect a fraction $\frac 1e$ not to occur at all, also $\frac 1e$ to occur exactly once, $\frac1{2!e}$ exactly twice, and so on. Hence we expect about
$$ \frac{1000}{e}\left(\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}+\frac1{5!}\right)\approx 999.4$$
triples to occur at most five times. Thus a triple occuring at least six times is not *too* surprising, given that we expect there to be about $0.6$ such triples.

Admittedly "not too surprising" is not really a useful statement about a propability. We can use Poisson *again*. As the expected number of successes is $\approx 0.6$, the probability of no success is $\approx e^{-0.6}\approx 0.55$, hence the probability of at least one success is $\approx 0.45$, just slightly less than guessing a coin toss tight.

Comment: Thanks Hagen. So there's a 45% possibility of any number appearing six or more times within 1000 random digits. But what about the probability of a specific 3 digit number? Can that be extrapolated from your formula?

Comment: Sorry for that last question. Now I see. The chance of a 3 digit number occurring 6 or more times is 1 in 1683. For the record, these were my findings not for pi, but for 3 x pi. The numbers within the brackets are a) your formula and b) the observation. 0 (367.88, 369) 1 (367.88, 388) 2 (183.94, 167) 3 (61.31, 61) 4 (15.33, 14) 5 (3.06, 0) 6 (0.51, 1). A very close match, so great answer. Thanks. (By the way, the number that occurred 6 times was the mysterious number 153 from John 21:11. It has one occurrence in the first 1000 digits of pi.)